# Laptop overheates without charger

Tags: laptop, overheating

I'm just wondering why my laptop gets warm only WITHOUT battery charger? So strange.

I don't know actually a device which gets hot, I presume it's a CPU or a videocard. It's located at the left to touchpad of ProBook 4540s.

I've just supposed that in autonomous mode a cooler is restricted to push itself to the limit? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a problem with your battery as if your plugged in, your battery isn't really being used at all. So I recommend getting a check on your battery.